# linux Shell : Sort -k not working properly, is this a bug?

Tags: linux, shell, sorting

I want Sort the third and fourth column by numerical value.
Third column first.

But! As shown below, the first and third operations seem to be incorrect. The fourth column is not sorted by value!
Is it a "sort" bug?

```
moasm@moasm-pc ~ $ cat ~/Desktop/10.log
ain.log.237.1999
ain.log.237.298

moasm@moasm-pc ~ $ sort  -b -t. -k3n,4n   ~/Desktop/10.log 

ain.log.237.1999
ain.log.237.298
moasm@moasm-pc ~ $ sort  -b -t. -k4n   ~/Desktop/10.log 

ain.log.237.298
ain.log.237.1999
moasm@moasm-pc ~ $ sort  -b -t. -k3n   ~/Desktop/10.log 

ain.log.237.1999
ain.log.237.298
moasm@moasm-pc ~ $ sort  -b -t. -k3V   ~/Desktop/10.log 

ain.log.237.298
ain.log.237.1999
moasm@moasm-pc ~ $ sort  -b -t. -k3V,4V   ~/Desktop/10.log 

ain.log.237.298
ain.log.237.1999
moasm@moasm-pc ~ $ sort  -b -t. -k3V,3V   ~/Desktop/10.log 

ain.log.237.1999
ain.log.237.298
```

Comment: _image and links are not allowed_

Comment: Please include text as text, not as (links to) images.

Comment: To edit your question, use the 'edit' link beneath the question text.

Answer (score 0):

To use secondary sorting column, you need to specify `-k` several times:

```
sort -t. -k3,3n -k4,4n
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I feel that you are right!
Ask another question: If the number of columns is uncertain, sort by the last column, how to do it?

Comment: To ask a new question, open a new question.

Comment: ok, new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53000340/shell-sort-command-how-to-sort-by-the-last-column-the-number-of-columns-is-un